# jQuery event not triggering on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here goes my question..
[image]

/* I am using ajax to dynamically create table               */

```
 $(".n").click(function(){
      var id= $(this).closest('tr').find('td.ide2').html();

         //for displaying the table
         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admin/show', //We are going to make the request to the method "list_dropdown" in the match controller
           dataType:'json',
           data: {'id':id}, //POST parameter to be sent with the tournament id
           success: function(resp) { 

             for(var i=0;i<(resp.length);i++)
              {
                var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($("#unique-list"));

                $('<td />',{text:resp[i]}).appendTo(row);
                $('<td class="off-del glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></td>').appendTo(row);  

             }//end for loop
            } //end success
            });  //end ajax




          $(".off-del").click(function(){
          alert('hello');
          var id= $(this).closest('tr').find($(":first-child")).html();
          console.log(id);
          });
        });
```

the event click on `$(".off-del")` is not triggering automatically I have to write in console the name of the event then this event starts functioning. Is there any issue with class name generating dynamically and how to overcome

After i wrote the name of the event in console it works [image]

Comment: use event delegation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ajax calls *are* asynchronous.

Before the elements are appended via ajax, the click handler gets registered, which find no elements with `$(".off-del")`.

You should probably use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.

```
$(document).on('click','.off-del',function(){
    alert('hello');
    var id= $(this).closest('tr').find($(":first-child")).html();
    console.log(id);
});
```

Instead of `$(document)` you can use a static parent.

Answer (score 3):

When you set up an event handler in jQuery like this:

```
      $(".off-del").click(function(){
        alert('hello');
        var id= $(this).closest('tr').find($(":first-child")).html();
        console.log(id);
      });
```

you're telling it to go find the elements with class "off-del" in the document *right at that moment*.  Your ajax operations will add such elements, but it'll only happen after your attempt to set up the handlers.

Instead of that, you can set up the handler on the document object and take advantage of event bubbling:

```
$(document).on("click", ".off-del", function() {
      alert('hello');
      var id= $(this).closest('tr').find($(":first-child")).html();
      console.log(id);
});
```

You can set up the event handler that way any time you want, and it'll handle clicks from any ".off-del" element added at any time.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use event delegation for this - you could also just register the handler *after* you've appended all the HTML (inside the `success` callback)

```
for(var i=0;i<(resp.length);i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($("#unique-list"));
    $('<td />',{text:resp[i]}).appendTo(row);
    $('<td class="off-del glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></td>').appendTo(row);  
}//end for loop

$(".off-del").click(function(){
      alert('hello');
      var id= $(this).closest('tr').find($(":first-child")).html();
      console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because after your dynamically created html you are also supposed to load that event which will bind it to newly created html.

So create a function for event and make a call to that function after dynamically created html.