# Failed to get the value of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Select labeled Products. When I choose a product, a list of the colors of the products is carried and placed by jQuery from a list (ul) called Colors.

So far everything works perfectly. But when I try to get the value of a color using jQuery, I am encountering a problem.

When I use the Action 1 in the functions.js file, I can not pick the color value, but when I use the Action 2, I can take the value color.

What I want to know is if anyone can explain to me why the first action fails.

Thank you to anyone who can explain to me.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Checkbox</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <div>
                <select name="products">
                    <option value="0">Products...</option>
                    <option value="pant">Pant</option>
                    <option value="shirt">Shirt</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul id="colors" style="list-style:none;"></ul>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**functions.js**

```
// ---------- ACTION 1 : FAIL ----------
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="products"]').change(function() {
        var product = $(this).val();

        $.post('colors.php', {product:product}, function(colors) {
            if (colors !== '0') {
                $('ul#colors').html(colors);
            } else {
                $('ul#colors').html('Nothing...');
            }
        });
    });

    $('input[name="color"]').click(function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        console.log(color);
    });
});

// ---------- ACTION 2 : OK ----------
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="products"]').change(function() {
        var product = $(this).val();

        $.post('colors.php', {product:product}, function(colors) {
            if (colors !== '0') {
                $('ul#colors').html(colors);

                $('input[name="color"]').click(function() {
                    var color = $(this).val();
                    console.log(color);
                });
            } else {
                $('ul#colors').html('Nothing...');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**colors.php**

```
<?php

// connection
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$host = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=product';

$conn = new PDO($host, $user, $pass);

// search
(!empty($_POST['product']) && $_POST['product'] !== '0') ? $product = $_POST['product'] : $product = '0';


if ($product !== '0') {
    $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT color FROM products WHERE product = :product');
    $query->bindParam(':product', $product, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo "<li><input name=\"color\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" . $value . "\"> " . $value . "</li>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0";
}

?>
```

**products table**

id | product | color

---

1  | pant    | Black

2  | pant    | Blue

3  | shirt   | Green

4  | shirt   | Orange

5  | shirt   | Red

Comment: The input elements enter the DOM dynamically. Check event delegation. The `click` events in Action 2 work because it is bound after your `.post` call completes. while that in Action 1 fails because, the click handler is registered before ajax completes. Answered ***[a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32336579/3639582)***

Comment: @ Shaunak D Thanks by the help!

Answer (score 0):

When you page runs the code below in *ACTION 1*:

```
            $('input[name="color"]').click(function() {
                var color = $(this).val();
                console.log(color);
            });
```

The input element targeted does not exist yet; the element loads soon after the page loads. The best way to re-write that and maintain the position of the code is to use a delegated event:

```
$('#colors').on('click', 'input[name="color"]', function() {
    var color = $(this).val();
    console.log(color);
});
```

Comment: @PeterKA-Thanks by the help too!

Comment: No problem @Learning. Feel free to vote and accept this answer if you found it useful.